# iOS: Storing Non-User password

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, passwords

I need to store third-party username/password in my iOS application, what is the best and most secure way to do this? When my app first runs, it will need to talk to Google's Picasa to download private pictures to use for the app.  To talk to Picasa, I have to provide my username/password and storing in the code is not secure at all.

I've search the web, I see `Keychain` came up a lot, but how exactly do I pre-load my password into `keychain`?

Is there a configuration file in xCode somewhere to store passwords needed for web-services?

Thanks

Comment: Could you use Google+ SignIn classes? There seems to be some sort of integration with KeyChain already. https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/interface_g_p_p_sign_in?hl=fi

Comment: The single sign-on your referring to is the User credential. When the user runs the iphone app, the phone needs to get the developer's/admin's credential to download images.

Answer (score 1):

Think that you need to store the password in encrypted form. Pick some encrypting algorithm, generate the encrypted details. And in code have some method to decrypt it when needed.

You just don't want someone who would read your code as plain text to see the password.

Think that something as simple as splitting the password into separate strings and later joining them could be enough.

Here for example You have encrypted in code "My1Password":

```
#define R1        @"My" 

#define R2        @"Password"

+ (NSString *)generatePass{ return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@, R1, @(1), R2]; }
```

Comment: I'm afraid you would advise this solution. Other development languages has special configuration files that is not visible to any one else, why can't the same be done for xCode?

Comment: Did not know about such files, and don't think the xCode has them. Sounds like it could be quite useful, as all app have some sort of connection to web services. There might be some libs or xcode plugins for that which I'm not aware of, my solution is the fastest to implement really.

Comment: Is it possible for others to take hold of the binary bundle and use a tool to "reverse engineer" and read the source code? If that's possible, then they can read the password in plain text. See my post below.

Comment: Yeah i think it's always possible to reverse engineer code. On android you would use obfuscator, I'm guessing that the obfuscation is part of ios build as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a response to krzysztof above:

I'm in a catch-22 situation here as I can't seem to grasp the concept of feeding the password as parameter to another function. Aside from avoid others reading the source code in plain text, can't hackers obtain the binary file and reverse engineer to read the password in the source code (R1 & R2 in this case)???

Back to encryption, lets take the following line of code which Encrypt/Decrypt data:

```
NSData *encryptedImage = [RNEncryptor encryptData:imageData withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:@"A_SECRET_PASSWORD" error:nil];


NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:data withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:@"A_SECRET_PASSWORD" error:nil];
```

This is where I'm stuck... where do I store `A_SECRET_PASSWORD`?

Comment: You store it in code, but you want it not to be easy to find by someone who reverse engineer your code.